# Weird 2D physics in unity3d, making "Ballz" kind of game

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

As you see in the screenshot. When the ball hits between two colliders, it should do what red arrows shows. Instead it does what blue arrow shows. All the boxes in the game are perfectly next to each other.(Used an algorithm to make it perfect.).

I am using unity's own physics system. I only have this piece of code for the ball :

```cs
void Start()
{
    rb = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(10.0f, -5.0f) * 41f * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

What "Ball" game object has;

- Sphere Collider2D
- Bounce physic in Collider2D {friction set to: 0, bounciness set to: 1}

Those are enough to achieve exactly the same physics of Ballz game.

[image: This is ok]

When the ball hits an edge of a collider, one of these situation happens. This is okay, exactly what i want. But I do not want the same thing happen when the ball hits between two colliders.

I hope i'm clear enough.

Comment: Question are these object's destroyable?

Comment: @Eddge It will be, but not yet. why?

Comment: I was going to say tou could use a composite for it, so you wouldnt get resolutions for colliding with 2 colliders, You still could remove the collider but you would need to get the collision point and figure out which "object" it collided with and remove that.  The Composite can update during runtime.

Comment: I thought the same but i decided not to do that because it will not be efficient. The ball sometimes hits the boxes maybe 5 times in a frame.(When it goes in the middle of two boxes.)